# cursor automatically move from one uitextfield to other textfield in ios?

Tags: ios6, uitextfield

I have 4 uitextfield controls if textfield length is 1 move to next uitextfield and hitting backspace delete  one by one textfield text in reverse direction.

like ipad unlock passcode while startup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UITextField delegate method to move to the next text field:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == textFieldA) {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      [textFieldB becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == textFieldB) {
      // etc...
    }
return YES;
}
```

For the Delete or Backspace key you try something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Other than that, I don't know of any other ways to catch keyboard events in iOS.

Comment: Hi I tested the code above as far as I know the backspace does not use the delegate "textFieldShould Return", what is the next step to solve the question above?

Comment: To clarify your question - So you want the Return key to move to the next text field and the Delete key to move to the previous text field?

Comment: @Gavin if only hit the return key move to next textfield "textFieldShould Return",when editing changed i am set the target action of textfield method "textfieldidchange" its working.delete r backspace its not working.